# setup.bash Not found ros hydro

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, setup.bash

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have uninstalled ROS hydro, and tried to install it again but the setup.bash file is missing (i.e. not created). How can i fix that problem?

Thnx

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/160111/setup.bash-not-found-ros-hydro/) by [abd_el_mon3em](https://answers.ros.org/users/15516/abd_el_mon3em/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-05-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bastbeat](https://answers.ros.org/users/12796/bastbeat/) on 2014-05-03**:
Is missing, in a new workspace or in /opt/ros/hydro?

**Comment by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) on 2014-05-04**:
Check your catkin workspace for this file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are referring to the /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash file being missing then you might have only some ROS hydro pakcages installed but not some of the low level packages. Try to install the ROS base packages:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-ros-base
```

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2014-05-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0